# how do i transfer this form.cs code in my new class calculate?

Tags: c#

How do I transfer this from `form` to my new add class `calculate`?

```
      form.cs   
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int a;
    double b=0;

    //input
    a = int.Parse(textBox1.Text); //<-textbox1//

    //process
    b = (1.8) * (a + 32);

    //output
    MessageBox.Show(b.ToString(), "Fahrenheit");
    textBox2.Text=b.ToString();//
    }


  calculate.cs
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text;

     namespace calculator
       {
       class calculate
       {
       }
```

Comment: No question, commented out code ... what should this be?

Comment: Please properly format your question. Add explanations to what is the problem and what is the desired output. Explain what you researched in order to solve it. [How to ask...](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @GiladGreen it seems, he's asking the question here for the first time

Comment: @RahulKurup - I know :) that is why I'm saying what is missing in the question and referred to the how to ask

Comment: (im new sorry)
i need to transfer it in calculate.cs .class .. and call the class in form.cs

Comment: @PrinceJkc - that is fine :) Please show the calculate class (only relevant part of it) - do you have a function there you want to call? Then In the form class you want to call it right?

Comment: **using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace calculator
{
    class calulate
    {
    }**

Comment: Kindly check the solution i posted. And do comment, is that's what you require

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what i understand from your question, you want to create a class to calculate temperature based on user input in *TextBox1* and show it in *TextBox2*. If that is so, you can do this:

```
static class Calculate
{
    public static double Temperature(int input)
    {
        double result = (1.8) * (input + 32); 
        return result;
    }
}
```

Now you can call it using

```
Calculate.Temperature(*pass value here*);
```

For Eg:

```
int a = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
double result = Calculate.Temperature(a);
MessageBox.Show(result.ToString(), "Fahrenheit");
textBox2.Text=result.ToString();//
```

Comment: this place is awsome .. thanks your answer is the real thing!